# Codeigniter session expire on close not working

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-2

I want to override or set config item dynamically. If user logged in without checking remember me checkbox then I want to set sess_expire_on_close value is false and user not checked then sess_expire_on_close value is true. I used the following php code:

PHP Code:

```
if($this->input->post('remember')) 
$this->config->set_item('sess_expire_on_close', '0');

else

    $this->config->set_item('sess_expire_on_close', '1');
```

but this process is not working. When I closed then browser without checking remember me dialog then session expire value is set to be 0 but still session is live. If a set config the following value

PHP Code:

```
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE; --> config.php
```

then session will be destroy when closed browser but not store session value when I checked remember me checkbox.